# copy hexstream in a char buffer to be sent over network

Tags: c, networking, hex

Have hex stream of a packet "010001e0c000011000000004f1517431ef9"(copied from wireshark). Now trying to create a packet using this hex stream in my code. But copying this hex stream into Char buffer converts it into ASCII. Followed is the code. Want to send the Hex stream from my code into the network. Can any one show the way to correctly copy the hex stream into the buffer ?

Current code:

```
char buffer1[70];
strncpy (buffer1,"010001e0c000011000000004f1517431ef9",60);
```

Comment: You're starting with ASCII here, your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: how about try `\x01\x00\x01\xec` ... and so forth...

Comment: @Mat: i am trying to copy and send the Hex stream available to me. But i don't know the way to copy that as HEX stream. The given code above copies the hex stream as string into the "buffer1".

Comment: What you have in your code above is a plain string that happens to contain only valid hex characters, and you're copying it using string functions. [Edit] your question to be more clear about how you're receiving your data, and where exactly your problem is with copying it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'hex stream'. Hex is a *representation*, used when *printing*,. What you have in memory is *binary*, almost certainly in twos-complement format. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You shouldn't use `char` to store raw data, because `char` has implementation-defined signedness. Use `uint8_t` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've converted the binary content to a string when you copied it from Wireshark. The result is a string that represents the binary data in a hex Format.

Instead of revers the convertion you should use an appropriate methop to copy the data. Try Wireshark's feature "follow XXX stream" and take the "C Arrays" representation, where XXX stands for TCP or UDP.

*EDIT*:

You can also write a function that takes a C string and converts this string to the binary data.

```
uint8_t GetByte(const char* pHexByte)
{
    char c = pHexByte[0];
    uint8_t Result = (c <= '9') ? c - '0' : c - '@';
    c = pHexByte[1];
    Result = (Result << 4) | (c <= '9') ? c - '0' : c - '@';
    return Result;
}

bool_t HexStringToBinary(uint8_t *pBinary, size_t BufferSize, const char*pHexString)
{
    while (pHexString[0] && pHexString[1])
    {
        uint8_t DataByte = GetByte(pHexString);

        if (!BufferSize) return FALSE;
        *pBinary++ = DataByte;
        BufferSize--;
        pHexString += 2;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Your answer meets the requirement. But is it possible to convert "string that represents the binary data in a hex Format." to binary data in c?